# CSS display:table-cell container element too tall

Tags: html, css, select

I'm wondering if this issue could occur to anyone trying to display a select element inside a div that is of the display:table-cell type.

On http://dev.coinjabber.com/site/www.blockreward.io inside the div with the class input-group there is an element called select-container.

I would like for that element to not display any taller than the  element inside it.

I gave it a height:40px but its computed height is 55px for some reason.

How can I get it to dislpay evenly in one row, just as it does on http://dev.coinjabber.com (FYI: On there I have activated the "chosen" jquery so the select element gets hidden by that but upon initial load there's still an ugly effect where for a second or so you see the select element shifted down a bit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.select-container` div has a default `vertical-align` value set to `baseline` which is why it is sticking to the bottom of the parent div. You will need to set its `vertical-align` property to `top` so that it moves to the top of the parent div and gets displayed evenly in one row.

Adding this CSS to your stylesheet will solve the issue, I've tested it on your website and it works perfecly:

```
#search-form .input-group .select-container {
     vertical-align: top;
}
```

[image]